# Include parameters for spring shell before method

Tags: java, spring, spring-shell

I am working on a Spring Shell project. The tool is a command line tool to manipulate data in a database. There are commands like add user (which adds a record to a table in database). In order to execute any commands the user of the tool has to be connected to the database. I would like to be able to run this all in one line. The user of my tool should be able to write a command like the following.

--database connection string xyz --username abc --password mno add user --username bob --role AA_ADMIN --company Microsoft

Here the three parameters database connection string, username and password are required to run the add user command.

Below I have included some sample code it is from the spring shell reference docs

```
package commands;

import org.springframework.shell.core.CommandMarker;
import org.springframework.shell.core.annotation.CliAvailabilityIndicator;
import org.springframework.shell.core.annotation.CliCommand;
import org.springframework.shell.core.annotation.CliOption;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserManipulation implements CommandMarker {

    private boolean simpleCommandExecuted = false;

@CliAvailabilityIndicator({"hw simple"})
public boolean isSimpleAvailable() {
    //always available
    return true;
}

@CliAvailabilityIndicator({"hw complex", "hw enum"})
public boolean isComplexAvailable() {
    if (simpleCommandExecuted) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@CliCommand(value = "hw simple", help = "Print a simple hello world message")
public String simple(
        @CliOption(key = { "message" }, mandatory = true, help = "The hello world message") final String message,
        @CliOption(key = { "location" }, mandatory = false, help = "Where you are saying hello", specifiedDefaultValue="At work") final String location) {
    simpleCommandExecuted = true;
    return "Message = [" + message + "] Location = [" + location + "]";
}

@CliCommand(value = "hw complex", help = "Print a complex hello world message")
public String hello(
        @CliOption(key = { "message" }, mandatory = true, help = "The hello world message") final String message,
        @CliOption(key = { "name1"}, mandatory = true, help = "Say hello to the first name") final String name1,
        @CliOption(key = { "name2" }, mandatory = true, help = "Say hello to a second name") final String name2,
        @CliOption(key = { "time" }, mandatory = false, specifiedDefaultValue="now", help = "When you are saying hello") final String time,
        @CliOption(key = { "location" }, mandatory = false, help = "Where you are saying hello") final String location) {
    return "Hello " + name1 + " and " + name2 + ". Your special message is "  + message + ". time=[" + time + "] location=[" + location + "]";
}

@CliCommand(value = "hw enum", help = "Print a simple hello world message from an enumerated value")
public String eenum(
        @CliOption(key = { "message" }, mandatory = true, help = "The hello world message") final MessageType message){
    return "Hello.  Your special enumerated message is " + message;
}

enum MessageType {
    Type1("type1"),
    Type2("type2"),
    Type3("type3");

    private String type;

    private MessageType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

}

So currently, hw simple is a command that is required to be executed before running hw complex or hw enum command. I do not want hw simple to be a command instead it the message parameter within the hw simple command should be a parameter that is required as a prerequisite to run hw complex or hw enum. So for example the command that I would like to run is.

--message hw complex --message abc --name1 def --name2 ghi --time 7:98 --location: Seattle

Does anyone know how to do this? If it is not possible to do this I would like to hear that or any alternative ideas if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

- either make those 3 additional parameters (`database, username, password`) parameters of each and every command that require them (note that in your particular example, you would need to rename one of those `username` parameters [the one to connect to the DB, or the one that represents the user to add] as you can't have 2 parameters with the same name obviously).
- Use the `@CliAvailabilityIndicator` approach, similar to what is described in the example, where a first command (maybe named `use` or `connect`) first tests the connection with the 3 given parameters and stores them somewhere, so that any further "real" command (such as `add user`) can use those values.

Also note that you can actually use a combination of the two (*i.e.* use solution 2 to provide defaults, that may be overridden on a case by case basis by solution 1).

Lastly, please note that you'll never be able to have something like what you describe at the beginning of your question, as **command** names must be at the beginning and they can't contain `--` (**options** do)